# Restricting admin access to url pattern in Symfony2

Tags: php, security, symfony

I'm developing a small back-office in Symfony2 and I would like users granted with `ROLE_ADMIN` to only be able to access pages with a `^/admin/` URL pattern (and also `^/logout$`).

So far I've managed to restrict other users from accessing these pages using access control:

```
// security.yml
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern:    ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security:   false

    secured_area:
        pattern:    ^/
        anonymous:  ~
        form_login:
            provider:       fos_userbundle
            csrf_provider:  form.csrf_provider
            login_path:     /login
        logout:
            invalidate_session: false

access_control:
    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/register$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: ^/, role: ROLE_USER }
```

But I can't find how to restrict admin users to these pages. What would be the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Is the rest of the site password protected for normal users too? Is it just that admin have additional rights or are you saying that if they are logged in they should not be able to access public pages?

Comment: I added the rest of my `security.yml` file. Basically everything is forbidden to non-logged users, and normal users have access to everything but `/admin` pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is one of conception and not of programming. By definition, an administrator has access to all of the pages, that's what an administrator is for. To counter your problem you could either modify the `role_hierarchy` in the **security.yml** file:

```
role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN: ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN
```

What that means is that, whatever a ROLE_USER request, the ROLE_ADMIN can access. If you remove that hierarchy, you could have an administrator **NOT** have an access to the user pages.

The option I would recommend is to simply create a new role, something like `ROLE_MANAGER` which can only access the `^/admin/` URL, this would be more appropriate for your case.

Comment: Creating a new role sounds like the best solution. However I changed the `^/admin/` access control rule to `ROLE_MANAGER` and granted my former admin the `ROLE_MANAGER` status and it's still able to access other pages (I demoted it from `ROLE_ADMIN` using the console and re-logged in).

Comment: I would also suggest changing the pattern _^/admin/_ to something like _^/manage/_ just to be consistent.
Be careful also, you want your admin to be a manager and a user as well.

Comment: As far as i know, everyone that is logged in has the role `ROLE_USER` so your `ROLE_MANAGER` will have `ROLE_USER` so will be able to see everything. To make sure `ROLE_MANAGER` could only see that specific directory you would need to set another allowed role to the `^/`. You would probably need to have a forwarding page as the login destination that has `ROLE_USER` that would forward users to their specified directory... that or create an authentication listener.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether `ROLE_MANAGER` is `ROLE_USER`or not, as long as `ROLE_MANAGER` is the only one that can access the `^/manage` section, it's all fine

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is most likely a little hidden gem in FOSUserBundle. If you login as an admin and then check the profiler you will see that your user has both ROLE_ADMIN and ROLE_USER, which is why they can access your secured pages. If you look in the Model of the FOSUserBundle you'll see in the User class that when you call getRoles() on a user there is always a default role added to the array. This constant is set in the UserInterface class as ROLE_USER.

There are many solutions you could explore but probably the most straightforward is simply for you to use another role for your front-end users. If you use a role ROLE_CUSTOMER for example, admin users will not get this role unless you explicitly define it in the role hierarchy. That way, both sets of users will be restricted to their respective sections.

Answer (score 0):

Use this form:

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

For more information click on the following link - http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html

Comment: I have already done that to prevent non-admin users accessing `^/admin/` URLs. What I trying to do is preventing admin users from accessing the rest.

Comment: @Jukurrupa If you don't want admin users from accessing the rest of the application, then they're not really admins.